# Make viewFs and hdfs Hadoop FileSystem work together with same kerberos prinicipal and keytab

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, kerberos

I want to use hdfs settings that have the defaultFs with the hdfs scheme. The settings also have settings to be able to mount viewFs. I would like to create 2 FileSystems one for hdfs and one for viewFs. I'm mostly going to be using the viewFs FileSystem.

I created the FileSystem using `FileSystem.get(uri, hdfsClientCfg)`.
That works and I'm able to make both file systems work as needed. The problem is kerberos tgt expiration. The kerberos tgts getting issued have a expiration time of 1 day.

After a restart for the 1st 24 hours everything works well. But after 24 hrs the viewFs FileSystem throws kerberos errors like:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$1.run(Client.java:775)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1836)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.handleSaslConnectionFailure(Client.java:738)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:828)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$3500(Client.java:424)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1575)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1398)
    ... 55 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed
    at jdk.security.jgss/com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.saslConnect(SaslRpcClient.java:409)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupSaslConnection(Client.java:628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2200(Client.java:424)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:815)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:811)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1836)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:810)
    ... 58 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.ietf.jgss.GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
    at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:162)
    at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:126)
    at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getMechanismContext(Krb5MechFactory.java:193)
    at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getMechanismContext(GSSManagerImpl.java:218)
    at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:230)
    at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:196)
    at jdk.security.jgss/com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:203)
    ... 67 common frames omitted
2023-05-15 04:44:42.660 [grizzly-http-server-7] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client  - Exception encountered while connecting to the server : javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
2023-05-15 04:44:42.661 [grizzly-http-server-7] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler  - Exception while invoking ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo over phx6-2pz.prod.uber.internal/10.94.29.179:8020 after 9 failover attempts. Trying to failover immediately.
java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]; Host Details : local host is: "<local-host-name>"; destination host is: "<namenode-ip>":8020; 
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:782)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1518)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1452)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1362)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:116)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:838)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor248.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:409)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:346)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:1749)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$27.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$27.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1476)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1476)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:442)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.viewfs.ChRootedFileSystem.getFileStatus(ChRootedFileSystem.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.viewfs.ViewFileSystem.getFileStatus(ViewFileSystem.java:380)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1437)
```

The point to note is that the hdfs FileSYstem does. not have this issue, it keeps refreshing it's tgt fine.
I authenticate the FileSystem at the start using `UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(principal, keytab);`

How do I access the tgt the viewFs is using? Where is this stuff stored?

I started a thread to run every 16 hours to refresh the tgt using `UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser().checkTGTAndReloginFromKeytab();`. This didn't do anything. I still saw errors after 24 hours.